# replacing elements in list when certain condition met

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a python script, where currently if a defined text file has certain phrases that match a list, it will remove them from the file.

Relevant list code snippets are as follows:

```
replacements = {'pc-123456 alert good-name-here':'',
                'pc-123456 alert remove-name-here':'',
}
```

Where the first half within the { is the direct text from the alert file and the:'', is to clear the text from the file if it matches. Currently, this works.

I need to add the following to the replacements list in my script, where:

```
replacements = {'12-Dec-19 00:00 pc-123456 alert good-name-here':'',
                '12-Dec-19 00:01 pc-123456 alert remove-name-here':'',
                '12-Dec-19 00:01 pc-234567 alert remove-name-here':'',
}
```

But I want to remove any detail that is defined as 'remove-name-here' (including date/time, name of device etc)., even though the alert will occur across more than 2 devices (eg. pc-123456, pc-2345678, pc-356435, pc-4563255) etc.

What's the simplest way to remove the whole text line if the script picks up a different device name for the same alert name, and to remove the time stamp (that is not defined currently within the replacements list)?

Rest of code is as follows:

```
lines = []
with open('path/to/file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        lines.append(line)

with open('path/to/same/file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using regular expressions instead of fixed strings.

Comment: Use regular expression instead.

Comment: Can there be other replacements besides just an empty string?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have so far

Comment: @kendriu edited. I know I will need to use regular expressions, but unsure how I can do this elegantly and correctly.

Comment: @Barmar the left hand side of inside the replacements is an input from an already existing text file, the right hand is removing the ones that are not needed, (eg. the remove-name-here). The good-name-here is just an example, these don't need to be removed. I'm looking for a solution to remove the ones that are described as the remove. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: FYI, they're called keys and values in a dictionary. My question is whether the values (the right hand sides) are always empty strings, or can there be other replacements?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what is at the end of a line you can do something like this:

```py
to_remove_endings = ['to_remove_ending']
lines = []

with open('path/to/file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        next_line = line
        for ending in to_remove_endings:
            if line.rstrip().endswith(ending):
                next_line = '\n'
                break
        lines.append(next_line)

with open('path/to/same/file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

You can also look for substrings:

```py
unwanted = ['substring 1', 'substring 2']
lines = []

with open('path/to/file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        next_line = line
        for substring in unwanted:
            if substring in line:
                next_line = '\n'
                break
        lines.append(next_line)

with open('path/to/same/file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks @kendriu, I tried your first edit, but I have multiple 'names' that I have to remove eg. 'to_remove_ending_1' ,'to_remove_ending_2' etc. How can that be implemented? It seems to duplicate each line if I try more than one name.

Comment: There was a bug in my previous implementation. Try now.

Comment: You can replace the `for substring` loop with `if any(substring in line for substring in unwanted):`